# NameError Occured when I add element into database

Tags: python, django, ipython, nameerror

I am getting this error again and again and I don't know why I tried everything but does not seem work,
I am trying to add element into mine home page!

```
from django.db import models
class ToDo(models.Model):
      name  = models.CharField(max_length = 200, unique = False)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDo, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
    complete = models.NullBooleanField()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

my text is defined in that code but I don't understand why I am getting this error and I tried everything

```
In [35]: lt.item_set.create(text = "moon", complete = False)
Out[35]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    392                         if cls is not object \
    393                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 394                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    395
    396             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    698     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    699     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 700     output = repr(obj)
    701     lines = output.splitlines()
    702     with p.group():

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in __repr__(self)
    519
    520     def __repr__(self):
--> 521         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)
    522
    523     def __str__(self):

~\Desktop\Django\Roman\Apple\funsite\apple\models.py in __str__(self)
     16
     17
---> 18         def __str__(self):
     19                 try:
     20                         return self.text

NameError: name 'text' is not defined

In [36]: lt.item_set.create(text = "moon", complete = False)
Out[36]: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    700                 type_pprinters=self.type_printers,
    701                 deferred_pprinters=self.deferred_printers)
--> 702             printer.pretty(obj)
    703             printer.flush()
    704             return stream.getvalue()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in pretty(self, obj)
    392                         if cls is not object \
    393                                 and callable(cls.__dict__.get('__repr__')):
--> 394                             return _repr_pprint(obj, self, cycle)
    395
    396             return _default_pprint(obj, self, cycle)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\lib\pretty.py in _repr_pprint(obj, p, cycle)
    698     """A pprint that just redirects to the normal repr function."""
    699     # Find newlines and replace them with p.break_()
--> 700     output = repr(obj)
    701     lines = output.splitlines()
    702     with p.group():

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py in __repr__(self)
    519
    520     def __repr__(self):
--> 521         return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)
    522
    523     def __str__(self):

~\Desktop\Django\Roman\Apple\funsite\apple\models.py in __str__(self)
     16
     17
---> 18         def __str__(self):
     19                 return self.text

NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

I don't understand it correctly why i am getting that error

Comment: Can you run that in a normal shell (without Ipython)? That `NameError` is very weird considering it occurs on `self.text` and says that `text` is not defined, even if for some reason `self` didn't have the attribute `text` it should have given an `AttributeError` instead.

Comment: yes normal shell doesn't showing me any error

Comment: You might want to add some related tags to your question then example [tag:ipython], etc. Also those [tag:google-bigquery] and [tag:sublimetext2] make _no sense_ in your question...

Comment: I am a beginner and I am learning that platform how to use it by learning from you and others users as well

Comment: Why did you remove the [tag:ipython] tag? You seem to not understand the purpose of tags. They help people who _follow_ those tags to find your question. So you editing out `ipython` and adding `sql`, `sqlite` and `database` does not make sense as your problem is with `ipython` (As you say it works in a normal shell) not with `sql` or `sqlite` or `database` (How would experts in these tags help you if your problem is not even related to these?)

Comment: thanks for that to give your precious time to tell me where i am making mistakes

Answer (score 1):

- first, in your terminal, `cd` to your project folder and activate **venv**
- after modifying your code in `models.py`, run `pyhton manage.py makemigrations`
  [if you already executed the command, you will see a file in that **apps migrations folder** like `0001_initial.py`]
- then run `python manage.py migrate`

If your problem still exists, provide some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any migrations and run them to create the field `text`? If not then you need to run them with `./manage.py makemigrations` `./manage.py migrate`.

Comment: I created text field and run that lines in normal shell